# ZXing truncading negative bytes

Tags: zxing

In ZXing i'm creating a string of a binary data using the encode "ISO-8859-1"
but somehow negative bytes in the data get truncated to byte 63 when reading the produced QR code

Example: String before QR code (as bytes)

```
-78, 99, -86, 15, -123, 31, -11, -64, 77, -91, 26, -126, -68, 33
```

String read from QR code:

```
63, 99, 63, 15, 63, 31, 63, 63, 77, 63, 26, 63, 63, 33
```

How do I prevent that without using base64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason ZXing assembles the QR matrix with the correct data, it's the reading that truncates the bytes. I ended up sidestepping the problem by encoding my binary data to base64 and dealing with the increased message size